# Sublime's vintage_start_in_command_mode not working

Tags: sublime-text-2

I have a very simple and confusing problem. I enabled Vintage in Sublime and I also added `"vintage_start_in_command_mode": true`. However, every time I open a file, it starts me in insert mode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

make sure you add that to your "user" settings, not to the "default" settings. it worked for me on windows and osx installs of st2. i added that line to my user settings, then opened a new file and it started in command mode.